# Is reading multi files line by line possible?

Tags: c#, file

I have tool to process text. Tool has 6 memo (memoEdit - devexpress). But when user input large text (50-100k line each memo), exception thrown **error out of memory**

To avoid this exception, i allow user chose file to process. Tool will read file each line and process each line then write to file result.

But my problem is how to read line 1 of 6 input file at the same time ? Or line 2... line n ?

Please help.

## Update

- User input html link >> to process new html link
- User input Title >> to process new Title
- User input Description >> to process new Description.
- User input image link and other links and template.

My work is process and mix all user input to one file.

## Update

Tool work well but when export or write result file, thrown exception.

That why i think i need read input file and write result line by line. But problem is how to read 4-6 file same line at same time. Ex: read line 1 of 6 file ?

Comment: Why do you need to read 6 files at the same time?

Comment: Is that 100000 characters per line?

Comment: We cant really help you unless you tell us what the process is. Why do you need all this information in memory? Chance are, you will have to get clever and lazily read/page the data.

Comment: User input html link, title, description,content.. to build a template.

Comment: i updated question with user request and my work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running out of memory. It is that simple. The quantity of your data is exceeding your RAM. What size are the files? Add them up then compare it to the memory you have on your PC.

Remember that c# strings are Unicode - 16 bits per character. Your text files may be 8bits per character but it will always be 16 bits in memory.

Comment: What is the reason you can't read each file one line at a time to avoid running out of memory?

Comment: Are you asking me? Sure you can read the file line by line but that depends on the process that is applied to the data. If it displays the lines on screen then the optimization is more complicated. If it is parsing text to integers (for example) then it is simpler. The OP has failed to correctly describe the domain. I have left him such a comment but the result is that the answers will fail to fully address his/her issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My computer running window 7 utimate 64bit with 8Gb ram. File size input is 50-100k line (~30-60Mb each file). I process all and show result on memo. I used StringBuidder result = new Stringbuilder(); result.Append(processedstring); result.AppendLine().

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue before which I was able to solve by breaking the work into batches:

1. Read inputs 1 to 6.
2. Combine the data
3. Write a few lines to a file on disk.
4. Append a few more line to the the file on disk.
5. Repeat step 4 and step 5 until all data from step 2 is written to the file on disk.

Done!

Comment: Thanks. But if follow your step... it's put all data to memmory and process >> exception out of memory.

Comment: I want to other way to avoid this exception, because C# cant make deeper in system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get your question because it sounds trivial, but we'll get to what's troubling you by seeing if something is an answer, and if not - why.

So, here's my suggestion. It assumes you have files with equal number of lines (given that you said that you combine the content of the files). Of course, your files should probably go separately to be processed individually, but you'll get the idea.

```
List<System.IO.StreamReader> files = new List<System.IO.StreamReader>
                     {
                            new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\file1.txt"),
                            new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\file2.txt"),
                            new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\file3.txt")
                     };
int lineCount = 0;
bool hasMore = true;
while(hasMore)
{
   foreach(var file in files)
   {
       string fileLine = file.ReadLine();
       hasMore = fileLine != null;
       //add your processing here...
   }

   lineCount++;

}

file.Close();
```